# Is it possible to pass custom GET parameters when using the NGSI query method?

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I'm trying to send personalised parameters through `ngsi_connection.query` function (e.g., `NEW_PARAMETER`). Is it possible? if so, how?

```
this.ngsi_connection.query(entityIdList, attributes, {
                        details: true,
                        limit: options.pageSize,
                        offset: (page - 1) * options.pageSize,
                        NEW_PARAMETER: "MY VALUE",
                        onSuccess: onNGSIQuerySuccess.bind(null, onSuccess, page),
                        onFailure: onError
                    });
```

**Note:** of course I have already test it, and the only parameters that seems to be included in the request are: limit, details, offset, as showed below.

```
<Request 'http://MY_IP:MY_PORT/v1/queryContext?limit=20&details=on&offset=0' [POST]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the only supported parameters are the ones listed by you: `limit`, `details` and `offset`. AFAIK, these are the only GET parameters used by the NGSI v1's query operation. Please, open a new ticket in the [ngsijs repo](https://github.com/conwetlab/ngsijs/issues) explaining if there are more GET parameters for the query operation or if you want to add those GET parameters for other purposes :).

Comment: ok, thanks for replying. It won't be need for adding a new ticket; though. The reason of my additional parameters was different than those aligned on the NGSI API